# How to express jquery ajax call with only javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you help me convert this jquery to javascript? Thanks.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a.false").click(function(e) {
                $(this).closest("tr.hide").hide("slow");
                var main_id = this.title;
                var display = "false";
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/useradminpage",
                    data: {main_id: main_id, display: display},
                    success: function(data) {
                    //display_false();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript. You can read its source code if you want to extract certain bits to use without loading the whole library.

Comment: What value does it give it to you to **not** use jQuery?? jQuery **is JavaScript** and renders your code much easier to read, more maintainable, cross-browser...all in all, less pain in writing certain scenarios and less bugs.

Comment: @Juri really? "easier to read and more maintainable". Is my example really harder to read?

Comment: @Raynos It is -- not that it's not a well written example -- but jQuery [if used correctly], like any higher-level abstraction, can make code "easier and more maintainable" ;-) [jQuery -- or other such libraries -- also takes care of a number of browser quirks including even trivial ones like `addEventListener` vs `attachEvent`.]

Comment: @Raynos I'd say: yes :). The problem is majorly if you have a good JavaScript programmer he codes also without jQuery and might be productive and write good code as well. But if you take the avg. programmer, he'll commit much more bugs, write uglier, less maintainable, horrifying code and would probably need a lot longer. On the other side, jQuery would provide him a higher abstraction, he has to write less code (hence commit to less bugs) and the code will result in being more maintainable and readable as well :)

Comment: @Juri you just said "bad programmers write bad code. Give them something restrictive like jQuery or Java to minimize damage". I say [WRONG](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McAeQiLmEYU). Hire better programmers. Get your programmers to learn how to program.

Comment: @Raynos Sure, but that's not always possible. It's not only about the "bad" devs, it's about the avg ones. jQuery just prevents you by committing to silly bugs in that it solves them for you, once and forever. That's the point of having some sort of framework/library (which btw doesn't mean you shouldn't study what's going on behind!!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, but your going to have to learn ES5, DOM4 & XHR2.

```
// Create the toArray utility
var toArray = function (obj) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = obj[i];    
    }
    return arr;
};
```

You need an `toArray` utility to manipulate NodeList and HTMLCollection.

```
var as = toArray(document.getElementsByClassName("false")).filter(function (el) {
    return el.tagName === "A";
});
```

Here you need to get all the `class='false'` elements and then filter then by whether they are `<a>` elements.

```
as.forEach(function (el) {
    var parentTr = el.parentNode;
    do {
        if (parentTr.tagName === "TR" && parentTr.classList.contains("hide")) {
            return; 
        }
        parentTr = parentTr.parentNode;
    } while (parentTr !== null);
```

For each element you want to find the parent `<tr>`. You do this by looping up the parentNode chain as shown. You also need to handle the `parentTr === null` case more elegantly

```
    el.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
        // Make a CSS3 animation class
        parentTr.classList.add("hide-slow");
        var main_id = this.title;
        var display = "false";
```

Attach a click handler. Change your jQuery hide animation to be done with hard ware accelerated CSS3

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "/useradminpage");
        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (ev) {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHTTPRequest.DONE) {
                // display_false();   
            } 
        });
        xhr.send({
            main_id: main_id,
            display: display 
        });
```

Open a XHR2 request. Point it at your url with the GET method. Then attach a readystatechange listener and finally send data down the request.

```
    }); 
});
```

**Disclaimer:** Browser support is a pain. You will need the following shims

- [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)
- [DOM-shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim)
- XHR2 shim doesn't exist. I'll write one at some point.

**Further reading:**

The interfaces I have used are

- [Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-element)
- [EventTarget](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-eventtarget)
- [XMLHTTPRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-xmlhttprequest-interface)

You should also read up on [ES5.1](http://es5.github.com/)

Comment: Some *newer* browsers support [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll).

Comment: @pst yes but you should only use QSA when you need it rather then when you are lazy.

Comment: @Raynos I use libraries because I'm lazy. I don't care what the library uses as long as it "just works" :-) Just pointing it out, largely because I just learned of it a week ago...

Comment: @pst I like hand optimising! I also dont know whether I should use QSA for QSA("tag.class")